# C Programming pointer cast Error - assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

Could you please help me in resolving following cast error. Here is my code:

```
int (*hook_parse) (netsnmp_session *, netsnmp_pdu *,u_char *, size_t);
.
.
netsnmp_pdu* tpdu=NULL;
.
.
char buf[65537]="", sep='|', sep1[]="bc_sep1";
.
.
buf[tpdu->community_len] =sep;
buf[tpdu->community_len] =sep1;   //This Line gives error
```

The error I got was:

```
api.c:: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

For **sep** I don't get such error, but for **sep1**, which is a string, I face the above error.

Comment: `int netsnmp_pdu * ;` what exactly is *that* supposed to be? Did you mean `int *netsnmp_pdu;` ? Or perhaps `typedef int *netsnmp_pdu;` ? Regardless, `sep` is `char`, `sep1` is `char[8]`, they're not synonymous in type as expressions (or anything else, for that matter).

Comment: Which line exactly it is giving that warning ? What is `community_len` declared as ? Please Elaborate.

Comment: @Amol its the last line, assigning `char*` to `char`.

Comment: type of `buf[tpdu->community_len]` is  `char`, type of `sep1` is `char *` (char[8] ==> char*)

Comment: made the required edits..

Comment: It is because `buf[tpdu->community_len]` is a `char`, so assigning it with `sep` which is a also a `char` (similar types) is okay. But `sep1` is a `char*`.

Comment: You need one more edit; where you tell us what the line triggering the error is *supposed* to be doing. What are you trying to do with that line of code?

Comment: i want assign the value of "sep"1 into **buf[tpdu->community_len]** just like sep

Comment: You want to store seven `char`s in one?

Comment: @raymelfrancisco , so what i need to do to  correct it?

Comment: @Akansha `strcpy(buf, sep1)` will do, but I think what you want is an array of strings. What does `tpdu->community_len` do? Is it changed or incremented in some other parts of your code?

Comment: @raymelfrancisco it get incremented!!!

Comment: Seems what you need is a string array. If that's the case, `char buf [how_many_strings][how_many_chars]`, `buf[tpdu->community_len][0] = sep;`, `strcpy(buf[tpdu->community_len], sep1)`

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not add a cast** to silence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

`buf` is an array of characters.
`sep` is a character.
`sep1` is an array of characters.

`buf[x]` is an element in the array (one character).

You can assign a character (sep) to a character array element.
You cannot assign another array (sep1) to a character array element.

Comment: No, you can't. `buf[x]` is a `char` therefore you have to put a char in it. `sep1` is not a char. It is not clear what you expect it to do.